# Getting all tags with multiple attributes with SoupStrainer and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all the occurrences of the 'td' tag when the class attribute has one of a few different values.

I know how to do this with BeautifulSoup after the fact but due to the amount of time it takes I'm trying to speed it up by selectively parsing each page with SoupStrainer. I at first tried the below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
strainer = SoupStrainer('td', attrs={'class': ['Value_One', 'Value_Two']})
soup = BeautifulSoup(foo.content, "lxml", parse_only=strainer)
```

Does anybody know of a way to make this work (it doesn't have to involve SoupStrainer or even Beautiful Soup)?

Comment: with `soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url), 'lxml')`, then `soup.find_all('td'))` should find all `<td>` tags, no?

Comment: Yes, I know. But I'm only trying  trying to parse part of the document (the td tag with the the few possible class attribute values). Your answer parses the whole thing then selects the td tags. I want to combine it in one step.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you may mean, of course. You might be able to use scrapy which gives you the ability to formulate xpath expressions such as the one used here. It takes advantage of the fact that the two `class` attributes are similar. Many other ways of making selections are available.

```
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> selector = Selector(text=open('temp.htm').read())
>>> selector.xpath('.//td[contains(@class,"Value")]/text()').extract()
['value one', 'value two']
```